# I javac my program on console but it didn't work(Linux)

Tags: java

I'm new at Java and I have a question.

I wrote this code.

```
{string isim = "Ali";boolean özne == true;if ( özne ){ System.out.println("Merhaba" + isim); }}}
```

When I javac it in console, it says:

```
Muz.java:5: error: ';' expected
 boolean özne == true;
             ^
1 error
```

What I need to do to fix this?

Please HELP ME!!!

Comment: Write `=` instead of `==`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `=` instead of `==` to affect `true` to your `boolean` variable, and the correct spelling for the class string is `String`.

You will also need to declare your class, I don't see it in your code snippet but in your case it should be something like that knowing that the name of your file is `Muz.java`

```
public class Muz {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String isim = "Ali";
        boolean özne = true;
        if ( özne ){ 
            System.out.println("Merhaba" + isim); 
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`==` is not appropriate there. Use `=` to do initialization.

Answer (score 0):

Assignment uses "=", not "==". Just delete one equal sign, and it will work fine.